# Add the same content to multiple pages

Tags: pages, content

I have a website with over 500 pages. Dont ask why but none of these pages have any content in them. I have created a page layout to be added as a single wp bakery block and want to add this same block to all pages but I cant see a way of doing this without going through everypage and doing it manually. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org). [`wp post create`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/create/) will create a post.

`wp post create ./file.txt --post_status=Publish`

where file.txt contains the content you want to add (in HTML format).

To post it multiple time use a `for` loop.

You can use [wp post update](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/update) if you want to update existing post.

First step check your post ID using

```
wp post list
```

Now update the post

```
wp post update <ID_1> --status=Publish --from-post=<ID_2>
```

Where ID_1 is the ID of the page you want to copy TO and ID_2 is the id of the page you want to duplicate from.

Comment: This is really interesting, thanks. So if I have a post, call it id 1, with the correct content and I want to apply that to 760 other pages how would I do that? And would it replace advanced custom fields or just the text content?

Comment: to clarify, the only part I want to change on each part is to add the wpbakery part in